# Does a Paladin with the Divine Health feature destroy a Green Slime?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin, environmental-hazards, disease

The [Green Slime](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/adventure-environments#GreenSlime) (DMG, p105) is a dungeon hazard, and

> any effect that cures disease [...] destroys a patch of green slime.

A Paladin, from level 3, is immune to disease thanks to the [Divine Health](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin#DivineHealth-265) feature. Does that mean that, if a Green Slime drops on one, it is destroyed? Or would the slime only be destroyed by some *restoration* spell that said it cured a disease?

Comment: No, but if a patch of green slime ever became a level 3 paladin, it would be instantly destroyed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Immunity to disease is not the same thing as curing a disease. It's just an innate ability that prevents any diseases from affecting the creature.

A paladin's [Lay on Hands](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin#LayonHands-261) ability used to cure disease would work, however:

> Alternatively, you can expend 5 hit points from your pool of healing to cure the target of one disease or neutralize one poison affecting it.

Comment: Technically, Lay on Hands says: "As an action, you can touch **a creature** and draw power from the pool to restore a number of hit points to that creature, up to the maximum amount remaining in your pool." Do you think this would prevent Lay on Hands from being used to destroy green slime? Or would you say the green slime's description creates a more specific exception than the general rules of Lay on Hands?

Comment: @V2Blast I'd consider a green slime to be a creature. It is capable of reacting to other creatures and has blindsight.

Comment: Fair enough! That makes sense.

Answer (score 15):

No. A Green Slime is destroyed by "an effect that *cures* disease". A Paladin is *immune* from disease. This effect is preventative (prophylactic), not curative.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Good first answer!